# How to solve $x'^2-1-2xx''=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution of:
>   $$(x')^2-1-2xx''=0$$

Is there a well-known technique for solving  this ODE?

Comment: A guessed solution is of the form $c\sin \omega t$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: but the actual solutions are only second-degree polynomials.

Comment: Along the lines of what Jack just said, one could attempt a series solution $x(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n t^n$. (This isn't necessarily a good idea, since this ODE isn't linear, but it can still be checked). One would then find $c_1,c_0$ can be chosen freely but $c_{n> 2}=0$, i.e. second-order polynomials of a certain form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you differentiate the equation again, you obtain

$$2x' x'' - 2xx''' -2x'x''= 0$$

This simplifies down to:

$$-2xx''' = 0$$

So if x is not indentically 0, $x''' = 0$, and thus you recover second order polynomials. From there, it's just a matter of checking which ones work.